# How to fix /bin/sh: gcc-11.3.0_1: command not found

Tags: r, gcc, compilation, rstudio

When trying to install `RTidyHTML` remotely from Github on RStudio (2022.02.2 Build 485) with R version 4.2.0, I'm told `/bin/sh: gcc-11.3.0_1: command not found`. This is after installing gcc through homebrew and creating an `~/.R/Makevars` with the following details:

```
VER=-11.3.0_1
CC=gcc$(VER)
CXX=g++$(VER)
CFLAGS=-mtune=native -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wconversion
CXXFLAGS=-mtune=native -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wconversion
```

Running `brew list --versions gcc`, return `gcc 11.3.0_1`,

Running `gcc --version` returns:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.27.3)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

My PATH is

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

`which gcc` returns `gcc is /usr/bin/gcc`.

I don't know how to make RStudio recognize the correct path and thus how I'm able to compile packages. I'd appreciate troubleshooting advice.

Running macOS Monterey (V12.2) on an M1 Mac.

Xposted on https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-troubleshoot-c-compiler-problems-on-mac/137675 but no response.

Comment: Downgrade gcc 12 to gcc 11: `brew install gcc@11`